# after successful response for an ajax request nothing happens

Tags: jquery

I have sent a jquery-ajax request and it's the response was true

but i need to change the value of a selected item on the page but neither the action takes place nor the the alert alerts

like :

```
$('#rename').click(function () {
//alert( $(this).closest('td').prev().prev().text());
var name = prompt('enter the new name');
if (name) $.ajax({
    url: url() + '/rename',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { value: name,
        id: $(this).closest('tr').find('td :first').attr('value')
    },
    success: function (result) {
        if (result.content == 1) {
            //location.reload();
            alert(name);
            //$(this).closest('td').prev().prev().text(name);
        } 
    }
})
})
```

what do you think to overcome that issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should help you debug the issue

```
$('#rename').click(function () {
    //alert( $(this).closest('td').prev().prev().text());
    var name = prompt('enter the new name');
    if (name) $.ajax({
        url: url() + '/rename',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { value: name,
            id: $(this).closest('tr').find('td :first').attr('value')
        },
        success: function (result) {
            alert('success');
            if (result.content == 1) {//location.reload();
                alert(name);
                //$(this).closest('td').prev().prev().text(name);
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('error');
        }
    })
});
```

basically added a couple of extra points.

1. How do you know success is happening and result.context just isn't equal to 1, so added the `alert('success');`
2. How do you know it's resturning success at all? Added

   error: function () {
               alert('error');
           }
3. you were missing a `;` at the end. :)

Comment: from firebug it responds with 1 and the value changed in the database
and i tried 

alerts success now

Comment: It worked fine now but that action doesn't work is it impossible or what to do $(this).closest('td').prev().prev().html(name);

Comment: think you need to open another question my friend!